# "Windows Date Format" in Excel on Mac

Tags: windows, ms-office

our internal software based on Zend throws Date Exception Errors for Excel Files from Mac Users. Same File stored on Windows passes.

So someone told me that in both OpenOffice and Excel for Mac (some here use the 2011 version) you can switch to "Windows Date Format" somehow but i can not find anything about this on google nor can i find it in the settings.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The instructions for switching to Windows date format on Excel for Mac can be found [here](http://mac2.microsoft.com/help/office/14/fi-fi/excel/item/e7cc2b0f-ee21-4aa7-af4e-156201a1e247).

So the steps are:

1. On the Excel menu, click Preferences.
2. Under Formulas and Lists, click Calculation.
3. Under Workbook options, select the Use the 1904 date system check box.

Comment: No, that's a different problem. That would just result in "wrong calculation" but what i talk about is a completely different format that can not be parsed.

Comment: Interesting, what does the date look like in the Mac file compared to the windows file?